How to use array in tact language?
I want to use multiple wallet address in ton chain network.
In Tact By example, There is map in tact instead of array.
So I made such code in blueprint.
message Withdraw {
    address: map<Int as uint16, Address>;
    amount: map<Int as uint16, Int>;
    length: Int as uint16 = 0;
}

But I don't know how to use this map in ts code.

How to use array in tact blueprint?

How to know length of map in tact?



https://docs.tact-lang.org/cookbook/data-structures

Thanks. It was little different from what I needed, But I found the way.
let amount = Dictionary.empty<bigint, bigint>();
amount.set(length, toNano("0.1"));```
